# How Can I Access Site.com Studio for a Community Builder Site After Winter '17?

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com, community-builder, platform-bug, authorization

> **Background:** Our community was always designed to be private - but
>   community builder lacked functionality that allowed us to select
>   individual access settings for every page or the builder site as a whole PRIOR to Winter '17. This
>   meant we couldn't use Community Builder to adjust access permissions, or get users pushed to our branded community builder login page.
>
> Ultimately, we ended up accessing Site.com studio (which used to be an
>   option from the community builder menu) and we used Site.com studio
>   settings to change the entire site to "requires authorization". This
>   resulted in every page redirecting you to the default Salesforce login
>   page - not ideal, since it wasn't our branded community builder login page, but
>   at least it was secure and required login.

Now, with Winter '17, Salesforce has fixed a lot of flaws in Community Builder that stopped us from being able to make the community private while simultaneously fixing our ability to use our branded login page. I staged this all in sandbox on a new community for testing purposes, and was ready to setup production today.

Unfortunately, it appears that Salesforce removed Site.com Studio as an option from Community Builder, and I can't seem to find my way in through other means (Not super familiar with it, to be honest). **This unfortunate oversight means that I can't find a way to turn off the option in site.com studio that has my entire site set to a global 'requires authorization' setting**. Since this Site.com Studio "Require Authorization" is still set globally on the entire site, it is overriding all of my other newly changed settings in Community Builder.

> **Problem:** Thus, I am between a rock and a hard place - Salesforce fixed all of
>   the issues that I've been calling their support department about for
>   months, but while doing so, they restricted my access to the old
>   Site.com Studio editor which is where I was forced to setup my
>   "workaround" login restriction prior to Winter '17. Now I can't seem
>   to turn that option off, which means that even though Salesforce fixed
>   everything - I can't use any of it until this global option is
>   disabled somehow.
>
> **Question:** How can I gain access to Site.com Studio for this site to disable this option? Can I access Site.com Studio for this Community Builder site through
>   any other means? How does one usually access Site.com Studio for a
>   Visualforce (Non-Lightning Community Builder) community? Or, am I out of luck unless I contact Support and hope that they can escalate it to someone who can turn that option off for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to Communities | Builder

Now observe the URL .Remove of all the extra parameters after domain.The URL would look like below

```
https://googleflowauth-dev-ed--sitestudio.ap1.force.com/
```

This will open the site.com Studio for you using builder .

Comment: Thank you so much! Life saving information right here. Not sure why they removed our access link but glad to have an easy workaround.

Comment: This works nicely for experience sites using Aura framework/an Aura template. But LWR sites do not support this - the link to the Site.com Studio has been removed from LWR Sites (Administration) in Winter '23 Release - see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_sitecom_studio_lwr.htm&release=240&type=5

Comment: Good addition! LWR is reimagined and don't use the previous studio so it won't work..